# What does it means " Incorrect syntax near end of file. Expecting TO" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table named `Scholarship` and I need to add two columns `test` and `test2`.

```sql
alter table Scholarship
    add [test] datetime
    add test2 int
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That statement won't produce the error of the title *in the supported versions*. What else is in the file? What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you using an old version where multiple `ADD` clauses weren't allowed?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well I am new at this. I am using MSSQL 2014. There is just a table named Scholarships and I am trying to add those two test coloumns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding multiple columns to a table, you only need one `add` keyword, and you need a comma (`,`) between the columns:

```sql
ALTER TABLE scholarship ADD
[test] datetime,
[test2] int
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but didn't work. After using comma it showed error in [test2]1

Comment: What error are you getting? The syntax is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12e1f8a1e655096afe7eb3fbf6941d67

Comment: My bad it worked